# How do I enable colored vertices in OpenGL ES (using GLKit)?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I started learning OpenGL this weekend, and discovered quite a learning curve. Most things I've managed to grapple through, but now I'm stuck...

I have created an array of vertices. Each vertex (vertexT) consists of 3 vectors (position, normal and colour). Each vector (GLKVector3) is a triple of floats (i.e., x,y,z or r,g,b). Since GLKVector3 is defined to be applicable to colors, I am assuming that opengl is happy to work with color values that do not specify a third float (ie alpha)

My function to setup my gl objects looks like this:
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArrayObject);

```
glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexT) * _vertexCount, [_vertexData mutableBytes], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertexT), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertexT), BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(GLKVector3)));
```

So far so good. I'm not using the color part of the interleaved array, and the whole object renders as white, using the following calls in my draw function:

```
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArrayObject);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _triangleCount * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, [_triangleData mutableBytes]);
```

So now I want to set up a per-vertex color for my model, so I added the following:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertexT), BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(GLKVector3)*2));
```

But it is still white. I managed to find [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820263) on SO that sounded like my problem, but the offered solution was to call glEnable with GL_COLOR_MATERIAL and as far as I can tell, this constant is not valid in OpenGL ES (according to the [sdk page](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml) at Khronos).

I'm sure it is something simple. But I'm not seeing it. A little help?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually found a way to enable color materials in GLKit.

This line does the trick:

```
self.effect.colorMaterialEnabled = GL_TRUE;
```

Comment: Are you sure that was the problem? I added your code to set the colours in an example I'm working on to draw two triangles. It worked first time without setting the colorMaterialEnabled anywhere. I'm new to OpenGL-ES also.